# Given a integer number, find the smallest function that given it

Tags: algorithm, math, compression

I have a very large positive integer number (million digits). I need represent it with the smallest possible function, this number is variable, it means, I need an algorithm that generates the smallest possible function to get the given number.

Example: For the number 29512665430652752148753480226197736314359272517043832886063884637676943433478020332709411004889 the algorithm must return "9^99". It must be able to analyze numbers and always return a math function that represent the number. Example the number 21847450052839212624230656502990235142567050104912751880812823948662932355202 must return  "9^5^16+1".

Comment: Is it an exercise ? homework ? if yes, put it clearly.

Comment: For your answer, the fastest way, if number are sorted is to use dichotomy else do a classic loop.

Comment: @gspr: For a very simple example, which is smaller, `1048576` or `2^20`?

Comment: @Stephen: I probably just misunderstood what he meant by "small" in the question.

Comment: This question is currently impossible to answer - please define your terms more clearly.

Comment: Your best bet is to use the algorithm you generated the number in the first place. Also see my answer below.

Comment: @David: it's not just "currently" impossible, it's impossible.  The Kolmogorov complexity of a string is not computable.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  It sounds like what you really want to do is compress some data..

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft: yes, it is. I'm trying to create some compress that uses this algorithm, but by the way this is impossible.

Answer (score 13):

Heard of [Kolmogorov complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity)?

To answer your question: unless you restrict yourself to some specific set of functions, it's impossible.

**EDIT:** Even in your example, how do you know that the shortest representation of 21​847​450​052​839​212​624​230​656​502​990​235​142​567​050​104​912​751​880​812​823​948​662​932​355​202 is actually 9^5^16+1? Isn't it a quite hard to *prove* even in this *specific case*?

If you restrict yourself to some set of functions then you can use the following algorithm:

```
For i = 1 to n
  enumerate all strings s of length i
    if s represents a valid expression according to rules chosen a priori, 
      and evaluates to the number in the input,
        return s
```

It is guaranteed to halt because on the last iteration of the outer loop (i = n) you will get eventually to a string contains the input verbatim.

Of course, this is not very efficient. Specifically O(b<sup>n</sup>) where n is the length of the input and b is the size of the alphabet.

Comment: Ok, I can restrict to some set of functions.

Comment: @Frederico: Even if you restrict, it will still be the case that for the vast majority of numbers, the shortest "function" that evaluates to that number will simply be the number itself.  Although the example you gave can be compressed to "9^99", most numbers can't be.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on @ybungalobill's terse answer, your function is equivalent to a function that computes the Kolmogorov complexity of an arbitrary string.  (The equivalence is obvious if you treat each digit of your very large numbers as characters, and the numbers as sequences of characters.)

According to the Wikipedia page on Kolmogorov complexity, the `K(s)` function that gives the complexity of a string `s` is [not a computable function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity#Incomputability_of_Kolmogorov_complexity).  (The page includes a proof.)

In other words, the algorithm you want simply does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

> @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft: yes, it is. I'm trying to create some compression that uses this algorithm, but by the way this is impossible.

That's because it's technically impossible to compress arbitrary data, for the same reason, but that doesn't stop us from doing it :)

There are much better ways of compressing data, however.  Take a look at, for instance, [LZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel-Ziv).  It is so ubiquitous that you can almost certainly find a library to do the compression for you, regardless of what language you're writing in.  [DEFLATE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE_%28algorithm%29) is another popular one.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not looking for optimality, just a reasonably good job, then there are a bunch of heuristics you can use.  For example, try to decompose n using all of the following

```
n = a^k + b
```

for `k = 2, 3, ..., log n`, and pick the one with the smallest `a + b`, say.  You can compute `a` and `b` using `a = floor(n^(1/k))` and `b = n-a^k`.  Then recurse on `a` and `b`.

Of course, this uses only exponentiation and addition to find a good compression.  If you allow subtraction as well, use `a=round(n^(1/k))` instead and let `b` be negative.

Allowing multiplication as well makes it quite a bit harder because you would probably need to factor `n`.